# How much current does IC7805 device draw?

Tags: power-supply, power, 7805

How much current does a IC7805 regulator draws, when it drives a 1.5A load?

Comment: Linear regulator's Input current = Load current + Quiescent current (listed in datasheet).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SX Vishruth! *Always* look at the device datasheet, 99 times out of a hundred the answer will be in there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the datasheet and people need to do research before posting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LM7805 has a GND current that is almost invariant with output current.

[image]

Note that this is **not** always true. There are some old and hopefully mostly forgotten bipolar linear LDO regulators that have a huge spike in current draw for low input voltage and high current. The [LM2941](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2941.pdf) is one such part:

[image]

Edit: The current going into a linear regulator is the output current plus the Iq, as MarkU says. Iq is negligible near full load current (for a 7805) but at low current (say 1mA) most of the current is used in the operation of the regulator.

If you are operating anywhere near 1.5A continuously you should toss the 7805 and use a switching regulator. The power waste is huge- not from Iq but from the fact it's a linear regulator and can't have reasonable efficiency.